# Google Chrome returns wrong HTML

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

My input on PHP.

```
<a class="is-hidden-desktop">
    <a id="sessionPanel"> 
        <a class="navbar-item" onclick="$('#loginModal').toggleClass('is-active');$('#loginModalCard').animateCss('bounceInUp');" data-target="loginModal">
        Giri? Yap</a> 
    </a> 
</a>
```

[Chrome output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fdnk.png)

As you can see the links are not nested as I intended. I am using XAMPP.

Comment: If your screen size is 200x100 then what do you expect? `view-source:` wraps text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have nested `a` tags.

From [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements.
>
> Since the DTD defines the LINK element to be empty, LINK elements may not be nested either.